# unresolved external symbol _malloc

Tags: c, windows, driver

I am trying to create a driver using WDK.I need to use malloc in that driver.When I try to use that I got an error like malloc unresolved external symbol.I think that I have to include some library.But I am not sure .How can I resolve this error?

Comment: This is technically not a duplicate. The OP was trying to resolve a linker issue that is specific to the WDK. The dupe'd question is for more generic linking problems.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Windows Device drivers don't normally link with the C-Runtime.  The build environment for the DDK/WDK doesn't link with MSVCRT.  But there are memory allocation routines that can be used in kernel and driver programming.

See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff554389%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more details.

Side note:

I'm a bit worried that you did not mention that "free" was also an unresolved symbol. That suggests that you never call it, hence a memory leak in device driver code. ;)  Or does the WDK pull in an implementation of free() from somewhere?

Comment: @darkendemon - How about a big green checkbox to return the favor?

Comment: I have used MmAllocateNonCachedMemory to allocate memory.I forget to use Free .I do not know which function i have to use to free memory in driver programming .Can u guide me ?.I am new to driver programming.

Comment: MmFreeNonCachedMemory - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff554516%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: :I am using MmAllocateNonCachedMemory and MmFreeNonCachedMemory  its through exception .What type exception handling i have to use to catch that

Comment: What would be the equivalent of realloc?